# Is it possible to run a Tor relay or proxy on a Synology NAS with low RAM?

Tags: linux, nas, tor, synology-diskstation

When I recently bought a NAS for backups and local media service, I also had in mind that this would be my chance to finally contribute my internet bandwidth to the Tor network. My thoughts were: I have enough bandwidth, with this NAS I have a Unix machine running 24/7, what should be the problem? But when I started to look for the ways how to do implement it, I realized that the easiest way (running a Snowflake proxy via Docker) does not work because my NAS has not enough RAM for Docker to run. And all the How-Tos for installing Tor on Synology are way too old, as if nobody is doing that anymore. I'm not a pro here, I earn my money in other realms, so I do not have too much time to invest, but I've been using Linux for a long time now and have some basic network and Linux admin knowledge.

**My Question**: Is it possible at all to run a Tor relay (bridge, middle or guard) on a Synology NAS with only 512MB RAM? But without having to invest days of work?

**My setup**: NAS: Synology DS220j (512MB RAM, Realtek RTD 1296 quadcore CPU) with recent firmware 7.1.1 - Router: TP-Link WR841ND v9; Line: DSL w/ 52 Mbit/s down and 10 Mbit/s up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hardware is not enough to run even non-exit TOR relay (which have least memory requirements). The [minimum requirements](https://community.torproject.org/relay/relays-requirements/) for non-exit relay are 512MB **available** memory. But you need memory for the OS, applications you run. Also you processor is not very powerful and TOR operations include good amount of cryptographic activities which can be "hungry" for processor power.